# Is it possible to sparse-checkout only the files in a sub-directory of a git repo?

Tags: reactjs, git, tomcat

I want to deploy the contents of a React's build folder to tomcat's webapps directory.

The project on Github is called dashboard and it has a sub-directory called client which holds the development code as well as the production build file (/client/build). I want to pull the contents of that build file into a directory called dashboard/ in webapps/.

I've tried using sparse-checkout but what happens is the full path (/client/build) is placed in the dashboard directory. So instead of webapps/dashboard/*contents of build folder* the structure is webapps/dashboard/client/build/*contents of build folder*.

Is there a way to only extract the files from a folder with sparse-checkout or is there a way to configure tomcat to look into /client/build for the files it needs?

Comment: I am not an expert here, but would making the dashboard a symilink to client/build work?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use sparse checkout mode to check out a limited subset of files, but you cannot use this to *rename* the files.  If the file's name is `a/b/c/d`—note that file names don't contain folder names; `a/b/c/d` is just a file name; it is your OS, not Git, that insists on storing this as a file `d` within a folder `c` and so on—then as far as Git is concerned, that file's name is `a/b/c/d`.<sup>1</sup>  The sparse checkout code will check it out using that name.

What you *can* do quite easily is use `git archive` to produce a tarball or zip archive, then use any un-archiver that allows you to skip some number of pathname components; or, if you have just a single file to extract, use `git show` or `git cat-file -p` to extract the file, and direct the output of this command to a file.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm thinking about a general method of handling file renaming issues, but it's still in formative stages, and there's no guarantee that the Git project folks will buy into anything I come up with here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You've helped me understand the OS's logic better. I'm currently using a workaround solution now in the form of a simple bash script that copies all the files from the client/build directory to the webapps/dashboard directory, then deletes the client folder recursively. I'm think of adding the git commands to the script as well to so deploying will be a simple- `sh deploy.sh` command. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: In general, having a deployment program / script is a good idea - Git isn't a deployment system and works poorly when pressed into acting as one. On the other hand, really good deployment systems can be tricky as there are so many oddball cases (OS dependencies and the like) to worry about. But starting with a simple script you write yourself makes sense, yes.